# Navigationbar background image not fill navigationbar Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios9.1, xcode7.1

I need to add background image to navigationbar, I done the code but it shows below the status bar.How to display the image fully on navigationbar.(iOS 8).

[image]

What actually I need to achieve is like the image below
[image]

The code I used for navigationbar background image is

```
UIImage *navBarBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationBarImg"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBarBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
```

Comment: whats your image size

Comment: use image size of 320x64

Comment: Yes,It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make UINavigationBar transparent

```
[self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                     forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```